# Type error: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, google-maps

```
      lat        long       time
 0  39.991861  116.344372   2.823611
 1  39.979768  116.310597  22.263056
 2  31.235001  121.470624  13.141667
 3  31.248822  121.460637   1.805278
```

The above is a dataframe rep_points. When i run the code below, it gives an error

```
Type error: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

in the line where circle is made.

```
gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(rep_points['lat'][0], rep_points['long'][0], 11)
gmap.plot(df_min.lat, df_min.lng)
gmap.scatter(rep_points['lat'],rep_points['long'],c='aquamarine')
gmap.circle(rep_points['lat'],rep_points['long'], 100, color='yellow')  
gmap.draw("user001_clus_time.html")
```

How should i resolve this error? Ive tried using

```
rep_pints['lat'].astype(float)
```

and

```
rep_pints['long'].astype(float)
```

but it didnt work well

Comment: So `rep_points = rep_points.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')` or `rep_points = rep_points.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').dropna()` for remove rows with missing values (created by converting non numeric values) should working

Comment: @jezrael That's not even the same error. I am not sure that's gonna help

Comment: @iam.Carrot - OK, so reopened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is quite trivial,

1. You're using a `Pandas.DataFrame`. Now when you slice it `rep_points['lat']`, you get a `Pandas.Series`.
2. The `gmplot.scatter()` is expecting an `iterable` of `floats` not a `series` of `floats`.
3. Now if you convert your `Pandas.Series` to a `list` by using `rep_points['lat'].tolist()` It'll start working

Below is your updated code:

```
rep_points = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\carrot\Desktop\ss.csv', dtype=float)
latitude_collection = rep_points['lat'].tolist()
longitude_collection = rep_points['long'].tolist()

gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(latitude_collection[0], longitude_collection[0], 11)
gmap.plot(min(latitude_collection), min(longitude_collection).lng)
gmap.scatter(latitude_collection,longitude_collection,c='aquamarine')
gmap.circle(latitude_collection,longitude_collection, 100, color='yellow')  
gmap.draw("user001_clus_time.html")
```

Other things that helped to point it out:

1. `type(rep_points['lat'])` is a `Pandas.Series`
2. `type(rep_points['lat'][0])` is a `Numpy.Float`
3. to iterate over a `Pandas.Series` you need to use `iteritems`

Comment: If i use the above code i get the error TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration in line gmap.plot   @iam.Carrot

Comment: I referred to [this](https://github.com/vgm64/gmplot). can you please share your stack trace

Comment: latitude_collection = rep_points['lat'].tolist()
longitude_collection = rep_points['long'].tolist()

gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(latitude_collection[0], longitude_collection[0], 11)
gmap.plot(min(latitude_collection),min(longitude_collection))
gmap.scatter(latitude_collection,longitude_collection,c='aquamarine')

#gmap.heatmap(rep_points['lat'],rep_points['long'])

gmap.circle(latitude_collection,longitude_collection, 100, color='yellow')
       
gmap.draw("user001_clus_time.html")                              @iam.Carrot

Comment: @AkankshaC I need the stack trace not the code. When an exception is thrown then what is the error message and what threw the error.

Comment: @AkankshaC Please use the question to put in your `StackTrace` Use the edit question. Also, Why do you have `gmap.marker(rep_points['lat'],rep_points['lon'],title="Cluster") ` This code should not be there

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-188-7a522e6fc5f3> in <module>()
     49 
     50 gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(latitude_collection[0], longitude_collection[0], 11)
---> 51 gmap.plot(min(latitude_collection),min(longitude_collection))
     52 gmap.scatter(latitude_collection,longitude_collection,c='aquamarine')
     53

Comment: ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gmplot/gmplot.py in plot(self, lats, lngs, color, c, **kwargs)
    118         kwargs.setdefault("color", color)
    119         settings = self._process_kwargs(kwargs)
--> 120         path = zip(lats, lngs)
    121         self.paths.append((path, settings))
    122 

TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

Comment: @AkankshaC can you please update the question with this stack trace? It's tough to figure out things with this formatting. Also, the issue is the `zip` function the `lats` is not a collection. Where is the `zip` in the code?