# return row if distance between given point and each (df.lat, df.lng) is less or equal to 0.1km

Tags: python, pandas

My imports
https://pypi.org/project/haversine/

```
from haversine import haversine, Unit
```

I have this geocode = (37.504855525623, 127.04866656867) 
my dataframe looks something like:

```
  title created_at              lng                 lat
0   a   2019-01-16 21:21:11    127.04866656867   37.504855525623
1   b   2019-02-15 20:54:59    126.93494467808   37.558505360332
2   c   2019-02-22 17:57:02    126.8891543       37.5817986
3   d   2019-02-26 21:58:27       0                   0   
4   e   2019-02-26 21:58:55    127.06710898411   37.54394538898
```

For each row I want its (lat,lng) pair and compare it with geocode given above in first sentence.

I've tried `df.loc[haversine((df.lat,df.lng), geocode) <= 0.1, False] = True`
However this gives me

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

so I changed my dtypes to float by:

```
df = df.astype({"lng": float, "lat":float})
```

and when I check using df.dtypes it correctly specifit lat, lng as float 64. and still gives me same error.

haversine is a function in haversine package 
EDIT: haversine needs two pairs of geocode. ex: haversine( (lat1, lng1), (lat2, lng2))

similar posts but cannot implement on mine: [TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988348/typeerror-cannot-convert-the-series-to-class-float?rq=1)
[Type error: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668387/type-error-cannot-convert-the-series-to-class-float)

Comment: what does `haversine((df.lat,df.lng)` returns?

Comment: you need to give it two pairs of geocode so haversine((df.lat[0], df.lng[0]), (df.lat[1], df.lng[1])) which will return distance between two geocode in km by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` on two columns and filter the result:

```
filtered = df[(df[['lat','lng']].apply(lambda x: haversine(*x,*geocode), axis=1))<=0.1]

print (filtered)
```

Result:

```
          title created_at         lng        lat
0 a  2019-01-16   21:21:11  127.048667  37.504856
```

Comment: it returns TypeError: ('haversine() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given', 'occurred at index 0'). What is star sign in front of x and geocode?

Comment: If your `haversine` function takes two tuples as input, simply use `haversine(x, geocode)` instead.

Comment: omg it works! thank you so much. So in this lambda function x = (lat,lng)  since we've used apply on two columns?

Comment: As the other answer stated, your func accepts two tuples but you were passing two series objects. You need to get the value pairs of the two series instead.

Answer (score 1):

your function `haversine` accepts float values but you are sending it pandas series

you can vectorize the function to pass it series like this. Then it will call the function for each item and return array

if you use numba.vectorize then it will be more efficient as numba will compile the python function

```py
v_haversine = pd.np.vectorize(lambda x,y: haversine(x,y, geocode))

df.loc[haversine(df.lat,df.lng) <= 0.1]
```

Comment: gives me TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object.

Comment: this may be because v_haversine doesn't accept geocode parameter I changed it now